# MultiSelect Load Efficiency using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm looking for a more efficient way of loading a mutliselect list this theory could apply to many situations. The way I do it causes many queries and I was wondering if there is a way to do it in two db queries.

```
DB Table : users: fields= (userID, name)
       data: 1, Dan
       data: 2, Cory
       data: 3, Matt
DB Table : users_selected: fields(userSelectedID, userID)
       data: 1,1
```

Now with php I normally do the following:

```
<?php 
 $q = 'SELECT userID,name FROM users';
 $r = mysql_query($r);
 echo '<select id="assignToID" name="assignToID[]" multiple="assignToID">';
 while($e = mysql_fetch_array($r){
     //this is where you have to query the db each time... theres got to be a better way
     $q2 = 'SELECT userSelectedID FROM user_selected WHERE userID = "'.$e['userID'].'" ';
     $r2 = mysql_query($q2);
     $nr = mysql_num_rows($r2);
     if($nr>0){
        $sel = ' selected="selected" ';
     }
     else{
        $sel = '';
     }
     echo '<option '.$sel.' value="'.$e['userID'].'"'>'.$e['name'].'</option>';

 }
 echo '</select>'
?>
```

So above we have to query for every user we have in the DB in our loop. Is there a way using PHP array_merge or someway to just do one query for all the users then append weather they are selected or not... Just trying to find a more elegant and efficient solution.

Many Thanks

Comment: U checked my answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a way, to get what you need in 1 SQL Query.

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_selected
ON users.userID = user_selected.userID
```

This LEFT OUTER JOIN, should and will produce a complete set of recors from table users, witht he matching records (if available) from user_selected. If there is no match, the right side will just contain null.

Comment: Yes perfect I've only used LEFT JOIN till now. I need to start looking further into OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Actually this is not what Im looking for as the user_selected table will grow over time and you will to use PHP to make sure you dont have duplicate users.